# Is there a single git command to create a local branch from a remote branch that does not track the remote branch?

Tags: git

If I want to create a new local branch from remote branch `release/A`. I know I can do this

```
git checkout release/A
git checkout -b feature/A1
```

and I will have `feature/A1` checked out and ready for changes.

But I grow tired of having to issue two commands to do this. I could make a script to do this but git has so many tricks I wondered if there might be a way to do this in one command. I tried

```
git checkout -b feature/A1 origin/release/A
```

and it does create local branch `feature/A1` but also gives it a tracking branch against `origin/release/A`, which is not something I want. I will never update `release/A` directly; ultimately I would push `feature/A1` to remote before issuing a pull request against `release/A`.

To clarify; is there a single command that does the same as the following two commands?

```
git checkout release/A
git checkout -b feature/A1
```

Comment: I have tried to sync as you ask, I hope it's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply provide [`--no-track` to checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt):

```
git checkout -b --no-track feature/A1 origin/release/A
```

Comment: Excellent; just what I was looking for. Thank you.